# Dynamic threshold determination in array of dynamic numerical values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, numeric

I have an array of ~1000 objects that are float values which evolve over time (in a manner which cannot be predetermined; assume it is a black box). At every fixed time interval, I want to set a threshold value that separates the top 5-15% of values, making the cut wherever a distinction can be made most "naturally," in the sense that there are the largest gaps between data points in the array.

What is the best way for me to implement such an algorithm? Obviously (I think) the first step to take at the end of each time interval is to sort the array, but then after that I am not sure what the most efficient way to resolve this problem is. I have a feeling that it is not necessary to tabulate all of the gaps between consecutive data points in the region of interest in the sorted array, and that there is a much faster way than brute-force to solve this, but I am not sure what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own quicksort/select routine that doesn't issue recursive calls for subarrays lying entirely outside of the 5%-15%ile range. For only 1,000 items, though, I'm not sure if it would be worth the trouble.

Another possibility would be to use fancy data structures to track the largest gaps online as the values evolve (e.g., a binary search tree decorated with subtree counts (for fast indexing) and largest subtree gaps). It's definitely not clear if this would be worth the trouble.